# How do I make my ginga more stable?

Tags: capoeira, balance

As noted in [one of my earlier questions](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5525/when-training-spinning-kicks-is-it-more-important-to-prioritize-control-or-heig), I'm trying to get back into Capoeira. I'm trying to practice for 20 minutes or so each day, just going through the movements on my own in an empty room (the classes in town, unfortunately, still have not worked with my current schedule), but I'm running into an unexpected area of difficulty, the most basic move of the *[ginga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_capoeira_techniques#Ginga)*. I feel unstable during the part where I draw my leg back. I think that part of my problem is distribution of weight between my legs (I know that the weight is supposed to go some to the back leg, but that the front knee needs to remain bent. However, I feel like I'm just lurching backwards rather than shifting the weight). And, well, it leaves me disinclined to keep doing the motion because it just feels clumsy and ridiculous.

I've tried looking up a few videos on YouTube, but they all seem to be of the "these are the gross movements you're doing... do them with a partner to the music" persuasion. Is there anywhere with better tips for getting it right than "just keep doing it and you'll figure it out"?

I'm currently at work, but I'll try to post some video tonight so that you can see what my current movement is like and hopefully coach me towards what I can do better.

Comment: Might be two questions here, Sean.

Comment: That's true, I suppose. Well, no harm in splitting.

Comment: It is nice to see more question about Capoeira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Ginga a lot.

2) Do variations:

- Slow
- Fast
- Very low
- Very stiff
- Let your chest nearly touch your knees while doing the Ginga
- Switch directions
- Stop and reverse in mid-movement
- Do esquivas/cocorinhas while doing the Ginga

3) Strength training:

- Kettle-bell swings
- Squats
- Kneeling Squat Jumps

Answer (score 1):

Do the ginga for one hour straight non-stop and your body  will adapt to it and you will develop your style. That is an old trick passed down to me by my master and also been advised by students who have visited brazil for capoeira training.

Comment: {nods} But won't that just bake in bad habits?

Comment: By bake, you mean outcome as a bad habit? I don't think so the ginga will help create a foundation and your legs will start to shape and adjust t the movement. Of course flexibility plays a big part and yoga is very essential to develop it properly. The 1-hour ginga done by moving to different sides not only same direction will help teach the person how to move, what to do and think Foundation is very important just put some capoeira regional music and ginga to it, . At least best to first try then talk after then you can determine if it is effective enough to be used.